# How to convert all odt files in a folder into microsoft word files ?

Tags: command-line, conversion, libreoffice, microsoft-word

I have a folder with a lot of odt files from LibreOffice, I could open each one by hand and save it as a microsoft word file, but that would take a long time, is it possible to reach this goal using the command line ?

Comment: `unoconv -f doc *.odt`

Comment: @don_crissti why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `libreoffice` in batch mode from the command line e.g.

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to doc *.odt
```

or

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to docx *.odt
```